# Custom keyboard not working in Android Nougat devices

Tags: android-studio

I got a custom keyboard which works well in android marshmallow but not working in Android Nougat+ devices.
I got the issue after I made an notification function in my keyboard .
What should I do?

```
nSidesf =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(DungeonKey.this)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Dungeon Keys") 
        .setContentText("TIMES UP!!, Do your SIDES..")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        //.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) nSidesf.setVibrate(new long[0]);
    nSidesManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Issue has been solved. It wasn't about notification function. I had an option to open another app which is not installed in that device. That causes the app to force close when I run.